# How to Live Embed an Image from Google Drive into a Google Document

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-docs

I'm using Google Drive in my company's Google Apps account. I'd like to live-embed some images that live in Google Drive into a Google Doc that's used for reference. When I say "live-embed", I mean I want the image as shown in the Google Doc to reflect any edits to the image as they are synced with Google Drive.

I tried the standard "Insert Image" > "Google Drive" and navigated to the image like so:
[image: Choose Image from Google Drive]

However, I edited the image, checked Google Drive and ensured that Drive captured the edit, but the Google Doc did not (even after a couple of browser refreshes) - the Google Doc still showed the old version of the image.

I would prefer to not have the images in question be publicly accessible to anyone. They are currently shared with everyone in my company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, it's not possible to "live embed" images on Google Documents. See [Insert or delete images or videos](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en) to learn about how to insert images and what it's supported.

An alternative is to use Google Apps Script to replace the image.